# Converting PHP Output text into something readable

Tags: php

I don't know much about PHP so i thought you guys could help, well here's my problem. I'm using an API, specificly Riot's API to get some things from there, well anyway I wanted to know if it's possible to convert this:

```
{
 "id": 18420146,
 "name": "AP [Ahri]",
 "current": false,
 "slots": [{
     "runeSlotId": 2,
     "rune": {
         "id": 5273,
         "name": "Greater Mark of Magic Penetration",
         "description": "+0.87 magic penetration",
         "tier": 3
     }
 }, {
     "runeSlotId": 3,
     "rune": {
         "id": 5273,
         "name": "Greater Mark of Magic Penetration",
         "description": "+0.87 magic penetration",
         "tier": 3
     }
 }, {
     "runeSlotId": 1,
     "rune": {
         "id": 5273,
         "name": "Greater Mark of Magic Penetration",
         "description": "+0.87 magic penetration",
         "tier": 3
     }
 }, {
     "runeSlotId": 6,
     "rune": {
         "id": 5273,
         "name": "Greater Mark of Magic Penetration",
         "description": "+0.87 magic penetration",
         "tier": 3
     }
 }, {
     "runeSlotId": 7,
     "rune": {
         "id": 5273,
         "name": "Greater Mark of Magic Penetration",
         "description": "+0.87 magic penetration",
         "tier": 3
     }
 }, {
     "runeSlotId": 4,
     "rune": {
         "id": 5273,
         "name": "Greater Mark of Magic Penetration",
         "description": "+0.87 magic penetration",
         "tier": 3
     }
 }, {
     "runeSlotId": 5,
     "rune": {
         "id": 5273,
         "name": "Greater Mark of Magic Penetration",
         "description": "+0.87 magic penetration",
         "tier": 3
     }
 }, {
     "runeSlotId": 9,
     "rune": {
         "id": 5273,
         "name": "Greater Mark of Magic Penetration",
         "description": "+0.87 magic penetration",
         "tier": 3
     }
 }, {
     "runeSlotId": 8,
     "rune": {
         "id": 5273,
         "name": "Greater Mark of Magic Penetration",
         "description": "+0.87 magic penetration",
         "tier": 3
     }
 }, {
     "runeSlotId": 30,
     "rune": {
         "id": 5357,
         "name": "Greater Quintessence of Ability Power",
         "description": "+4.95 ability power",
         "tier": 3
     }
 }, {
     "runeSlotId": 22,
     "rune": {
         "id": 5289,
         "name": "Greater Glyph of Magic Resist",
         "description": "+1.34 magic resist",
         "tier": 3
     }
 }, {
     "runeSlotId": 23,
     "rune": {
         "id": 5289,
         "name": "Greater Glyph of Magic Resist",
         "description": "+1.34 magic resist",
         "tier": 3
     }
 }, {
     "runeSlotId": 28,
     "rune": {
         "id": 5357,
         "name": "Greater Quintessence of Ability Power",
         "description": "+4.95 ability power",
         "tier": 3
     }
 }, {
     "runeSlotId": 20,
     "rune": {
         "id": 5289,
         "name": "Greater Glyph of Magic Resist",
         "description": "+1.34 magic resist",
         "tier": 3
     }
 }, {
     "runeSlotId": 21,
     "rune": {
         "id": 5289,
         "name": "Greater Glyph of Magic Resist",
         "description": "+1.34 magic resist",
         "tier": 3
     }
 }, {
     "runeSlotId": 29,
     "rune": {
         "id": 5357,
         "name": "Greater Quintessence of Ability Power",
         "description": "+4.95 ability power",
         "tier": 3
     }
 }, {
     "runeSlotId": 19,
     "rune": {
         "id": 5289,
         "name": "Greater Glyph of Magic Resist",
         "description": "+1.34 magic resist",
         "tier": 3
     }
 }, {
     "runeSlotId": 14,
     "rune": {
         "id": 5331,
         "name": "Greater Seal of Mana Regeneration",
         "description": "+0.41 mana regen / 5 sec.",
         "tier": 3
     }
 }, {
     "runeSlotId": 18,
     "rune": {
         "id": 5317,
         "name": "Greater Seal of Armor",
         "description": "+1.41 armor",
         "tier": 3
     }
 }, {
     "runeSlotId": 17,
     "rune": {
         "id": 5317,
         "name": "Greater Seal of Armor",
         "description": "+1.41 armor",
         "tier": 3
     }
 }, {
     "runeSlotId": 16,
     "rune": {
         "id": 5317,
         "name": "Greater Seal of Armor",
         "description": "+1.41 armor",
         "tier": 3
     }
 }, {
     "runeSlotId": 11,
     "rune": {
         "id": 5331,
         "name": "Greater Seal of Mana Regeneration",
         "description": "+0.41 mana regen / 5 sec.",
         "tier": 3
     }
 }, {
     "runeSlotId": 15,
     "rune": {
         "id": 5317,
         "name": "Greater Seal of Armor",
         "description": "+1.41 armor",
         "tier": 3
     }
 }, {
     "runeSlotId": 27,
     "rune": {
         "id": 5289,
         "name": "Greater Glyph of Magic Resist",
         "description": "+1.34 magic resist",
         "tier": 3
     }
 }, {
     "runeSlotId": 10,
     "rune": {
         "id": 5331,
         "name": "Greater Seal of Mana Regeneration",
         "description": "+0.41 mana regen / 5 sec.",
         "tier": 3
     }
 }, {
     "runeSlotId": 26,
     "rune": {
         "id": 5289,
         "name": "Greater Glyph of Magic Resist",
         "description": "+1.34 magic resist",
         "tier": 3
     }
 }, {
     "runeSlotId": 25,
     "rune": {
         "id": 5289,
         "name": "Greater Glyph of Magic Resist",
         "description": "+1.34 magic resist",
         "tier": 3
     }
 }, {
     "runeSlotId": 13,
     "rune": {
         "id": 5331,
         "name": "Greater Seal of Mana Regeneration",
         "description": "+0.41 mana regen / 5 sec.",
         "tier": 3
     }
 }, {
     "runeSlotId": 24,
     "rune": {
         "id": 5289,
         "name": "Greater Glyph of Magic Resist",
         "description": "+1.34 magic resist",
         "tier": 3
     }
 }, {
     "runeSlotId": 12,
     "rune": {
         "id": 5331,
         "name": "Greater Seal of Mana Regeneration",
         "description": "+0.41 mana regen / 5 sec.",
         "tier": 3
     }
 }]
```

},

into like they appear in this website:

[HERE](http://www.lolking.net/summoner/euw/26204253#runes)

This image gives the id for each rune
[HERE](https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/riot-api/img/rune-slot-ids.png)

Comment: What do you mean by _"something readable"_ ? Try `json_decode()` as well

Comment: forget about the something readable, what i really want is to do it the way i edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// EDIT

Sorry stopped reading before the whole question was parsed.
Try something like this:

```
$api_response_string = ##your_string_here##;
$api_response = json_decode($api_response_string);


if(!empty($api_response)){
    echo 'Runepage Name: '.$api_response['name'].'<br />';
    echo '<table>';
    foreach($api_response['runes'] as $key => $elem){
         echo '<tr>';
         echo '<th>Runeslot Id '.$elem['runeSlotId'].'</th>';
         echo '<td>'.$elem['name'].', description: '.$elem['description'].', tier: '.$elem['tier'].'</td>';
         echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
}
```

With this code you convert the json_string to an array and then iterate over all the elements under the runes key and echo it out.

With a little bit of CSS magic you can enhance the view to meet your needs.

Steve

////

I use

```
function _debug($var){
    echo '<pre>'.print_r($var).'</pre>';
}
```

Steve

Answer (score 0):

Try checking out PHP JSON, a PHP extension. http://php.net/json

Relevant functions: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.json.php